# Is this Rails request proper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, query-optimization

Running the Rails for Zombies [tutorial](http://railsforzombies.org/levels/2/challenges/6), I'm trying to find how many weapons Ash has.

Here's how the zombies look:

```
Zombie.fin­d(:all­) 
[#<Zombie ­id: 1, nam­e: "Ash", ­graveyard:­ "Glen Hav­en Memoria­l Cemetery­">, 
 #<Zombie ­id: 2, nam­e: "Bob", ­graveyard:­ "Chapel H­ill Cemete­ry">, 
 #<Zombie ­id: 3, nam­e: "Jim", ­graveyard:­ "My Fathe­rs Basemen­t">]
```

as well as their weapons:

```
Weapon.find(:all ) 
[#<Weapon ­id: 1, nam­e: "Hammer­", strengt­h: 1, zomb­ie_id: 1>, 
 #<Weapon ­id: 2, nam­e: "Chains­aw", stren­gth: 3, zo­mbie_id: 2­>, 
 #<Weapon ­id: 3, nam­e: "Other ­Zombie", s­trength: 1­0, zombie_­id: 3>]
```

This works, but is it the best solution, or is there a faster/more concise way to express this request?

```
Zombie.fin­d{|a| a.nam­e == 'Ash'­}.weapons.­count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not the best solution. It will fetch all Zombies first, and then iterate over each of them to find the one named "Ash". What you should do is to use where call there:

```
Zombie.where(nam­e: 'Ash'­).first.weapons.­count
```

`where` is SQL call, so it will respond with ActiveRecord::Relation (kind of array), which will list all zombies named "Ash", in your case `[#<Zombie ­id: 1, nam­e: "Ash", ­graveyard:­ "Glen Hav­en Memoria­l Cemetery­">]`.

`first` because array will not become an instance even if there is only one zombie returned, so we will get instance we need:

```
[<Zombie ­id: 1, nam­e: "Ash", ­graveyard:­ "Glen Hav­en Memoria­l Cemetery­">].first
#=> <Zombie ­id: 1, nam­e: "Ash", ­graveyard:­ "Glen Hav­en Memoria­l Cemetery­">
```

The last part was correct.